# How to set a timeout to an apache c module

Tags: c, apache, apxs2

I have an apache module written in C, and I would like to limit execution duration of this module to 15 minutes. Is it possible?

Comment: Most browsers would have long since given up well before 15 minutes have elapsed

Comment: I don't use a browser: I send a request to my server that does a processing and returns me an answer.